# Being able to drag around Dynamically created Panels

Tags: c#, events, panel

I keep seeing posts about adding Events to be able to drag around the panel.  But how would i achieve this through a dynamically created Panel?

```
Panel pn = wch.GenerateWorkspaceControl(space.Name, space.Name, p);
            PanelTest.Controls.Add(pn);

        public Panel GenerateWorkspaceControl(string gbTitle, string gbName, Point gbPos)
    {
        Panel pnl = GeneratePanelContainer(gbPos, new Size(300, 200));
        pnl.Controls.Add(GenerateLabel(gbName,new Point(100,1),new Size(135,115)));
        return pnl;
    }

private Panel GeneratePanelContainer(Point loc, Size size)
    {
        return new Panel() { BackColor = Color.Transparent, BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle, Location = loc, Size = size };
    }
```

Do i add an event handler in the generate panel container?

to summarize i have a panel that is holding multiple panels that are dynamically created.  I want to be able to move around the dynmaically created panels INSIDE the main panel.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, `pnl.MouseMove += pnl_MouseMove;`  Make that method, and cast the sender object to a panel.

Comment: You can either write a coome set of events or Lambdas for those panels or you create a MoveController class to which you register the Panels. (I would prefer the latter.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a class that lets you make any control movable.

Simply register it:

```
MoveController.RegisterCtl( button1 );
```

Now you can move the control..

When done you can also unregister a control:

```
MoveController.UnRegisterCtl( button1 );
```

Here is the controller class:

```
static class MoveController
{
    static List<Control> Controls = new List<Control>();
    static Control curCtl = null;
    static Point curStart = Point.Empty;

    static public void RegisterCtl(Control ctl)
    {
        Controls.Add(ctl);
        ctl.MouseDown += ctl_MouseDown;
        ctl.MouseMove += ctl_MouseMove;
        ctl.MouseUp += ctl_MouseUp;
    }

    static public void UnRegisterCtl(Control ctl)
    {
        if (Controls != null && Controls.Contains(ctl) )
        {
            Controls.Remove(ctl);
            ctl.MouseDown -= ctl_MouseDown;
            ctl.MouseMove -= ctl_MouseMove;
            ctl.MouseUp -= ctl_MouseUp;
        }
    }

    static void ctl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        curCtl = (Control)sender;
        curStart = curCtl.Location;
    }

    static void ctl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (curCtl != null)
        {
            curCtl.Left +=  e.Location.X - curCtl.Width / 2;
            curCtl.Top  +=  e.Location.Y - curCtl.Height / 2;
        }
    }

    static void ctl_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        curCtl = null;
    }
}
```

**Update**

Here is a more involved version that allows

- to set a `Tag` value to restrict movement to vertical or horizontal
- adding `Actions` for `Moving` and `Moved` events..

---

```
class MoveController
{
    static List<Control> Controls = new List<Control>();
    static Control curCtl = null;
    static Point curStart = Point.Empty;

    static Dictionary<Control, Tuple<Action, Action>> 
        actions = new Dictionary<Control, Tuple<Action, Action>>();

    static public void RegisterCtl(Control ctl)
    {
        RegisterCtl(ctl, null, null);
    }

    static public void RegisterCtl(Control ctl, Action moveAction, Action movedAction)
    {
        Controls.Add(ctl);
        ctl.MouseEnter += Ctl_MouseEnter;
        ctl.MouseLeave += Ctl_MouseLeave;
        ctl.MouseDown += ctl_MouseDown;
        ctl.MouseMove += ctl_MouseMove;
        ctl.MouseUp += ctl_MouseUp;
        if (moveAction != null)
            if (actions.Keys.Contains(ctl)) actions[ctl] = new Tuple<Action, Action>(moveAction, movedAction);
            else actions.Add(ctl, new Tuple<Action, Action>(moveAction, movedAction));
    }

    private static void Ctl_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Control)sender).Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    }

    private static void Ctl_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Control)sender).Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }

    public static void UnRegisterCtl(Control ctl)
    {
        if (Controls != null && Controls.Contains(ctl) )
        {
            Controls.Remove(ctl);
            ctl.MouseDown -= ctl_MouseDown;
            ctl.MouseMove -= ctl_MouseMove;
            ctl.MouseUp -= ctl_MouseUp;
        }
        if (actions.ContainsKey(ctl)) actions.Remove(ctl);
    }



    static public void RegisterMovingAction(Control ctl, Action action)
    {

    }

    static void ctl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        curCtl = (Control)sender;
        curStart = curCtl.Location;
    }

    static void ctl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int t = 0;
        if (curCtl != null)
        {
            if (curCtl.Tag != null) t = Convert.ToInt32(curCtl.Tag);
            if ((t&1) != 1) curCtl.Left +=  e.Location.X - curCtl.Width / 2;
            if ((t&2) != 2) curCtl.Top  +=  e.Location.Y - curCtl.Height / 2;

            if (actions.ContainsKey(curCtl) && actions[curCtl] != null && actions[curCtl].Item1 != null)
                actions[curCtl].Item1();
        }
    }

    static void ctl_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (curCtl == null) return;  ///
        if (actions.ContainsKey(curCtl) && actions[curCtl] != null && actions[curCtl].Item2 != null)
            actions[curCtl].Item2();
        curCtl = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I got it working by doing something very similar to your post.  Never learned this stuff in school so it's all fairly new.  Also, i can't post because people downvoted me for not fully understanding controls and events? idk.  But i had another question if i could ask you in these comments? is it bad practice to have an event fire another event?  like a customindexchanged event on a combo box fire an event to change a label.

Comment: Sometimes I find myself doing this but I usually correct it and write the code as it ought to be. Here is the rule: control events shouldn't contain any lengthy code. Instead they should call a function (with a nice name) that does the work.

Comment: Example: A SaveButton should not do the saving. It should call a saveData function. And the SaveDataMenuItem should call the same function, not the saveButtonClick! When you want to change the GUI and do away with the OkButton no code chages are needed. In a wider context this is the separation of View and Model; so : Yes, It is bad practice, but sometimes one slips into it.