# C# image of map put pins and hover over info?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the map image below and using C# and winforms I want to create an application that will read a database and put pins on the map based on grid location. Then on mouse hover over the pins I want popup a small message box with a callsign and time the pin was put on the map. I can handle the database method of getting the data for each pin.

I am struggling to find the correct way to display the map image and put the pins on it ?

[image: maidenhead grid map]

Comment: So you have a map with a grid and a database. But how exactly are they related?? - Looks like a cylindrical projection? - Where does the tagged Dictionary come in?

Comment: I will just place pins at specific grid coordinated ie, the center of the square ...that isn't the issue I am having. I am not sure how to place the image, picturebox seems like the wrong answer. Then how do I place pins that will allow me to hover over the pin and get a little info popup?

Comment: Ah, well these are different issues then. Several options come to mind, depending on what else you want. If you simply want to display the map unscaled and place a couple of 'pins' on it, well why not a picturebox. You can create a Label subclass for the pins  and keep score in a List<yourPinClass>.  Its MouseHover coulld Show a Tooltip with a Text you store in that class. If you keep the class serializable you can save the list to xml.. - As lonf as you don't care about the stiff in your DB and the geometric relation to the map and the mouse locations it is simple...

Comment: Once to need scaling, well you need function to go both ways. And if you need to find the locations from the DB in the map you need a transformation/cylindrical projection to find which grid position the mouse is at. - To make the pins moveable see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423255/being-able-to-drag-around-dynamically-created-panels/45423971?r=SearchResults&s=2|20.2096#45423971)

Comment: You could also use a chart with the map as background and movable annotations, but I don't think rhis would be better..

Comment: Thanks I had not thought of using labels for the mouseover, that's a great idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a simple project but in WPF and database type is access.

- you will add a new user control. Name it "pin"
- replace xaml with this:

  ```
    <Grid MouseEnter="Grid_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="Grid_MouseLeave">
    <Ellipse x:Name="SmallImage" Fill="#FFE42507" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="13.347" Margin="6.333,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="13.667"/>
    <Path Data="M7.609,7.9881667 L7.609,17.126855" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19.332" Margin="12.403,12.212,0,-3.484" 
    Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1.953" 
    Panel.ZIndex="-1"/>
    <Popup Name="Info">
        <TextBlock Name="myPopupText" 
             Background="LightBlue" 
             Foreground="Blue" Text="{Binding Information}">

        </TextBlock>
     </Popup>
     </Grid>
  ```
- add the following code to this usecontrol

  ```
  public partial class pin : UserControl
  {
    public pin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

   public  string Information { get; set; }

    private void Grid_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Info.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void Grid_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Info.IsOpen = false;
    }
  }
  ```
- for the main window replace xaml codes with:

  ```
    Title="MainWindow"  WindowState="Maximized" d:DesignWidth="1045.5" 
     d:DesignHeight="587.5">
    <Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="Picture" Width="892" Height="523" >
        <Canvas.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="NqZeo.jpg"/>
        </Canvas.Background>

    </Canvas>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="+" Background="#FFD4D0C8" BorderBrush=" 
    {x:Null}" Click="button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="64" Height="50" FontSize="24"/>
    </Grid>
  ```
- finally the code for the main window

  ```
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
     {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadAllPinsFromDataBase(@"C:\Users\dell\Documents\Test1.accdb");
    }
    #region Load all pins
    public void LoadAllPinsFromDataBase(string PathOFyourDataBaseAccess)
    {
        string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+ PathOFyourDataBaseAccess ;
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = null;
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT X,Y,information FROM Table1 ", connection);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Addpin(Convert.ToSingle(reader["X"]), Convert.ToSingle(reader["Y"]),Convert.ToString ( reader["information"]));
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region Add new pin
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Addpin(10, 10,"new area");
    }

    #endregion
    #region Add pin
    void Addpin(float X, float Y,string Info)
    {
        pin addpin = new pin() { Information =Info};
        addpin.MouseDown += pinPressed;
        Picture.Children.Add(addpin);
        Canvas.SetLeft(addpin, X);
        Canvas.SetTop(addpin, Y);
    }
    void pinPressed(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MovableShape = (Control)sender;
    }
    #endregion
    #region move item
    Point startPt;
    public Control MovableShape { get; set; }
    private void MovShp_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        startPt = e.GetPosition(Picture);
        Mouse.Capture(Picture);

    }
    private void MovShp_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( MovableShape != null && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            var mp = e.GetPosition(Picture);
            double deltaX = mp.X - startPt.X;
            double deltaY = mp.Y - startPt.Y;

            var newX = deltaX + Canvas.GetLeft(MovableShape);
            var newY = deltaY + Canvas.GetTop(MovableShape);

            if (newX < 0)
                newX = 0;
            else if (newX + MovableShape.ActualWidth > Picture.ActualWidth)
                newX = Picture.ActualWidth - MovableShape.ActualWidth;

            if (newY < 0)
                newY = 0;
            else if (newY + MovableShape.ActualHeight > Picture.ActualHeight)
                newY = Picture.ActualHeight - MovableShape.ActualHeight;

            Canvas.SetLeft(MovableShape, newX);
            Canvas.SetTop(MovableShape, newY);

            startPt = mp;

        }


    } 
    #endregion
  ```

  }

Comment: replace the background of the canvas with your picture

Comment: I'm going to rewrite this to use sqlite instead of access, I don;t have a copy of access to create a data file :(

Comment: I got it working this morning, thank you very much! It will take me quite a while to figure out exactly what you did and why.