# Location on winforms panel is not accurate

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have been making a WinForms application with C# and using Visual Studio 2019 version and am experiencing a problem with the accuracy of the coordinate system in my code. I have some graphical elements (which are actually labels) and you can click on one and click on another place and it will be moved to that place, and this works fairly accurately when I just do it on the background of the app. But when I add a panel behind the graphical element, it does not work properly and instead moves the label a bit up. I illustrated this by drawing some lines on the panel. Here is my code for when it clicks inside the panel (which is called the Bonder):

```cs
private void Bonder_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mousePosInBonder = e.Location;

            foreach (GraphicalElement el in elementsInBonder)
            {
                if (el.Dragging)
                {
                    while (el.Dragging)
                    {
                        if (!(mousePos.X > el.Location.X && mousePos.X < el.Location.X + el.Size.Width && mousePos.Y > el.Location.Y && mousePos.Y < el.Location.Y + el.Size.Height))
                        {
                            el.Location = mousePosInBonder;
                            el.Dragging = false;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my code for drawing the lines (and clicking):

```cs
private void GraphicalElement_Drag(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            GraphicalElement el = (GraphicalElement)sender;

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (el.Dragging)
                {
                    el.Dragging = false;
                }
                else if (!el.Dragging)
                {
                    el.Dragging = true;
                }
            }
            else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                if (el.Bonding)
                {
                    if (BONDING_ELEMENTS)
                    {
                        g = Bonder.CreateGraphics();
                        g.DrawLine(bonder, el.Location, LAST_BONDED_ELEMENT.Location);
                        BONDING_ELEMENTS = false;
                    }
                    else if (!BONDING_ELEMENTS)
                    {
                        LAST_BONDED_ELEMENT = el;
                        BONDING_ELEMENTS = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is called when the element is clicked on (as Labels cannot be dragged).
This is the code for the GraphicalElement class which displays the element.

```cs
public partial class GraphicalElement:Label
    {
        // Attributes
        private bool dragging = false;
        private bool bonding = false;
        private string info = "";

        public GraphicalElement() { }

        public GraphicalElement(Element el)
        {
            Tag = el.ToString();
            Text = el.ChemicalFormula;
            AutoSize = true;
            Location = new Point(100, 100);
            
            info = el.Info;

            if (el.Type == "alkali metal")
            {
                BackColor = Color.Crimson;
            }
            else if (el.Type == "alkaline earth")
            {
                BackColor = Color.DarkOrange;
            }
            else if (el.Type == "transition metal")
            {
                BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else if (el.Type == "basic metal")
            {
                BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else if (el.Type == "semimetal")
            {
                BackColor = Color.Cyan;
            }
            else if (el.Type == "nonmetal")
            {
                BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
            else if (el.Type == "halogen")
            {
                BackColor = Color.Pink;
            }
            else if (el.Type == "noble gas")
            {
                BackColor = Color.DarkMagenta;
            }
            else if (el.Type == "lathanide")
            {
                BackColor = Color.HotPink;
            }
            else if (el.Type == "actinide")
            {
                BackColor = Color.Maroon;
            }
        }

        // Getters and setters
        public bool Dragging
        {
            get { return dragging; }
            set { dragging = value; }
        }
        public bool Bonding
        {
            get { return bonding; }
            set { bonding = value; }
        }
        public string Info
        {
            get { return info; }
            set { info = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }

    }
```

And this is the picture of what it looks like:
[image: What the lines look like when you draw them on the screen]

How do I fix this problem as it is quite misleading.

**EDIT**
This is where the element is added to the elementsInBonder:

```cs
private void GraphicalElement_Bond(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            GraphicalElement el = (GraphicalElement)sender;
            
            if (el.Bonding)
            {
                elementsInBonder.Remove(el);
                elementsOnScreen.Add(el);
                el.Location = new Point(1011, 43);
                el.BringToFront();
                el.Bonding = false;
            }
            else if (!el.Bonding && BONDER_ON)
            {
                elementsOnScreen.Remove(el);
                elementsInBonder.Add(el);
                el.Location = new Point(12, 43);
                el.BringToFront();
                el.Bonding = true;
            }
        }
```

It happens with a double click event.

And this is how I specify it in the beginning. `List<GraphicalElement> elementsInBonder;`. GraphicalElement is not a child of Panel as the Graphical Elements could be moved on and off the Bonder panel by jumping between the two lists: elementsOnScreen as well.

Comment: Because coordinates passed in the MouseEventArgs are relative to the container? However I fail to see how a click event receives mouse coordinates.

Comment: What is `mousePos`? -- You shouldn't be using `Bonder.CreateGraphics();`, you should draw your lines in the Paint event of your Panel.

Comment: @Jimi `mousePos` is the position of the mouse. It is a Point. I was trying to use `Bonder.CreateGraphics` as I was trying to make sure that the user could only bond the elements when they were in the Bonder, which is a Panel. Also, I was wondering, you mentioned the Paint event. Is it possible to call the Paint event from another method as I thought it was an event.

Comment: That Variable/Field is not defined anywhere and the controls positioning is the question's matter. -- Your Labels seem to be child of the Panel (`foreach (GraphicalElement el in elementsInBonder)`), but you should show how you add them anyway, because also `elementsInBonder` (among other things) is undefined (why don't you have `foreach (var el in Bonder.Controls.OfType<GraphicalElement>().ToList())`?). -- `Bonder.CreateGraphics()` is simply wrong.

Comment: To move a Label to p Point you will want to move its center to that point, right? So Label.X should be point.X - Label.Width/2 etc.. - And the 1st Click position is meaningless except maybe to identify the Label in  a List of Bounds, but the sender will be easier, as long as no overlapping Labels are allowed.. - For a more direct movement you may want to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423255/being-able-to-drag-around-dynamically-created-panels/45423971?r=SearchResults&s=2|20.2244#45423971)

Comment: @TaW I was first testing it by moving it to the direct location and them I am going to make it so that it goes to where you click on the GraphicalElement, but that does not work on the panel - it lags and instead moves it a few pixels above the expected height and I am trying to find a way to stop it from going a few pixels off.

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: Maybe you could try to adjust your from's property, `AutoScaleMode` to None, I guess your form size is change by font size so that you couldn't get the true position.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by mainly trial and error. The panel was slightly off the top left hand corner, so I wondered whether the GraphicalElements were off by the same amount that the panel was of by, which in this case was 12 pixels to the right and 43 pixels down. So then, the I changed the code to represent that.

For the Bonder_click() method, I changed the mousePosInBonder to represent it being a few pixels out like this:

```cs
private void Bonder_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mousePosInBonder = new Point(e.Location.X+12, e.Location.Y+43);

            foreach (GraphicalElement el in elementsInBonder)
            {
                if (el.Dragging)
                {
                    while (el.Dragging)
                    {
                        if (!(mousePos.X > el.Location.X && mousePos.X < el.Location.X + el.Size.Width && mousePos.Y > el.Location.Y && mousePos.Y < el.Location.Y + el.Size.Height))
                        {
                            el.Location = mousePosInBonder;
                            el.Dragging = false;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The line which I changed was `mousePosInBonder = new Point(e.Location.X+12, e.Location.Y+43);` whereas previously it was `mousePosInBonder = e.Location;`

For the line drawing, I did a similar thing:

```cs
private void GraphicalElement_Drag(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            GraphicalElement el = (GraphicalElement)sender;

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (el.Dragging)
                {
                    el.Dragging = false;
                }
                else if (!el.Dragging)
                {
                    el.Dragging = true;
                }
            }
            else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                if (el.Bonding)
                {
                    if (BONDING_ELEMENTS)
                    {
                        g = Bonder.CreateGraphics();
                        g.DrawLine(convalentBonder, new Point(el.Location.X-12, el.Location.Y-43), new Point(LAST_BONDED_ELEMENT.Location.X-12, LAST_BONDED_ELEMENT.Location.Y-43));
                        BONDING_ELEMENTS = false;
                    }
                    else if (!BONDING_ELEMENTS)
                    {
                        LAST_BONDED_ELEMENT = el;
                        BONDING_ELEMENTS = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In this, the line I changed was `g.DrawLine(convalentBonder, new Point(el.Location.X-12, el.Location.Y-43), new Point(LAST_BONDED_ELEMENT.Location.X-12, LAST_BONDED_ELEMENT.Location.Y-43));`.